# Content of Edittext not getting changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using an Edtitext in my code and its declaration inside main is as follows:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/url" 
    android:text="http://192.168.1.42:8080/NotifyServlet/serv"
    />
```

as i want one default value for my edittext.
but even after i am changing the value of it at run time and passing it as a parameter to another service its original value which i set in main.xml is getting passed.
Can anyone please suggest how should i handle it.
Thanks!!

Comment: post code where you set and get value from EditText

Comment: url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
String url_server = url.getText().toString();

Comment: final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timertask.class);     intent.putExtra(Parameter, url_server);

Comment: had set the value in main.xml only

Comment: so basically,you need to pass values when user changed it.i mean,not on onClick() of a button or so?

Comment: no..onClick() of a button only...when i am running my application and changing the content of edittext..which i already set in main.xml ...but after changing also it is passing the same value which is set in main.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume you execute

```
String url_server = url.getText().toString();
```

before actual value is set. This should be run in onClickListener()